# How to stop execution of Spring Boot application if Log4j is unable to access the log file?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have this Batch application which runs every half an hour. Recently the server went through certain activities due to which the owner of the log folder changed to the root user (A) instead of another OS user (B). This user B is responsible for executing the Batch Application jar and created the logs folder and files present inside it. But after the activities, all the ownership of the files present inside logs folder shifted to A.

Now, whenever the jar was getting executed, it started to throw the below mentioned errors in the console itself. And wasn't logging anything in the log file as it didn't have the permission to write on it.

```
2022-11-16 13:28:17,180 main ERROR RollingFileManager (/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:746)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:202)
    at com.test.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

2022-11-16 13:28:17,186 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@7d6f77cc] unable to create manager for [/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@5aaa6d82[pattern=/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/archived/SpringBootApplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=26214400)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@7d6f77cc] unable to create manager for [/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@5aaa6d82[pattern=/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/archived/SpringBootApplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=26214400)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:202)
    at com.test.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

2022-11-16 13:28:17,187 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:202)
    at com.test.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

2022-11-16 13:28:17,188 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2022-11-16 13:28:17,188 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile" for logger config "root"
2022-11-16 13:28:17,189 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile" for logger config "com.test"
2022-11-16 13:28:17,562 main ERROR RollingFileManager (/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:746)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.reinitialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.initialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at com.test.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

2022-11-16 13:28:17,564 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@7d6f77cc] unable to create manager for [/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@271053e1[pattern=/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/archived/SpringBootApplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=26214400)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@7d6f77cc] unable to create manager for [/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/SpringBootApplication.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@271053e1[pattern=/rootFolder/SomeFolder/logs/archived/SpringBootApplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=26214400)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.reinitialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.initialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at com.test.SpringBootApplication.main(SpringBootApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

.....

2022-11-16 13:28:17,566 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2022-11-16 13:28:17,566 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile" for logger config "root"
2022-11-16 13:28:17,567 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile" for logger config "com.test"
```

But the jar was continuously executing in the background. I wanted to ask is it possible to stop the execution of the application if the file is not accessable? Why should it run in the background if it is not able to log anything. It is a matter of audit and security hence I would like to stop the application.

I have been checking if there is a way to set the log4j bean manually instead of autoconfiguration but there doesnt seem to be any possiblility! Should it be handled programmatically then?

Your advice and helps are very much appreciated! Thank you in advance. Below is the log4j.properties which I use in my SpringBoot Application.

```
status = error
name = Log4j2PropertiesConfig

property.filename = /rootFolder/someFolder/logs

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}/Application.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${filename}/archived/Application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = false

appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=25MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = /rootFolder/someFolder/logs/archived/
appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = Application-*.log
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileCount.type=IfAccumulatedFileCount
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileCount.exceeds=30
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize

appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 25MB

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = com.ultimatix
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = RollingFile
```

I have been checking if there is a way to set the log4j bean manually instead of autoconfiguration but there doesnt seem to be any possiblility! Should it be handled programmatically then?

Comment: Hi, did you able to solve the problem? As I am currently facing the same. Any help